# Committed team vs dedicated team

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology, pronouns, programming

I want to express that I am managing a team that is responsible for API integrations. How is the best and tightest way to say it?

> 1. Managing a committed on API integrations team
> 2. Managing a team, committed on API integrations
> 3. Managing a dedicated team on API integrations
> 4. Managing a dedicated to/(on?) API integrations team

or something in between, or probably something entirely else?

Comment: *Managing the API Integration Team*. What else do you want/need to express?

Comment: Problem is that it's not "the" team. This team is newly created, part of set of many other teams, so it's not something that established. I want to stress on the fact that team is focused on this particular thing idk

Comment: *Managing the new API Integration Team*?

Comment: and how can I say that the team is comprised of people from my org and also from three more contractor organizations with a simple yet effective phrase?

Comment: *Managing the new API Integration Team Comprising Our Own Staff and Staff From Three Contractor Organisations*?  There is a limit to how much information you can get into a title before it becomes (a) a description and (b) ridiculous.

Comment: How is the team mix important?

Comment: Try workplace.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Options 1 to 4 all sound wrong to me. You said in a comment you want to stress that the team is focused on that particular thing, but saying "an API integration team" is enough to indicate that API integration is their focus, you don't need to add words like *dedicated*.

Answer (score 1):

The OP here is mistakenly interpreting ***dedicated*** as ***loyal, faithful, determined, devoted***. But in the context of a ***dedicated team*** the meaning is ***exclusively allocated, not assigned to anything else***.

[Merriam-Webster **dedicated**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedicated)

> **1:** ***devoted*** to a cause, ideal, or purpose : ZEALOUS
> *a dedicated scholar*
> *a novelist with a dedicated following*

> **2:** given over to a ***particular purpose***
> *a dedicated Web server*
> *The fees would be put into a dedicated fund for rebates that go directly to households and employers*

Being a "dedicated team" implies nothing at all about how "committed" the members of a team are to their work. It just means they *only* work on whatever project they're "dedicated, exclusively assigned" to. Syntactically, you might reasonably say...

> *I manage a dedicated API integrations team*
> *We're a team dedicated **to** API integrations*
> *Our a team **is** dedicated **to** API integrations*
> etc., etc.

---

EDIT
I didn't intend to imply that "a dedicated team" ***always*** implies "exclusively allocated" rather than "devoted" - but it ***usually*** does. In a context such as the exceptionally common sequence [***set up a dedicated team***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22set%20up%20a%20dedicated%20team%22), I would be astonished if anyone could find an example of that particular sequence having the latter sense.

Comment: Well, if you want to split hairs, obviously there will be contexts where *a dedicated team* means *a highly-committed team*. But in the vast majority of cases that's ***not*** what the collocation means, and it looks pretty obvious to me that OP's problem here turns on ignoring / being unaware of that context-specific difference in meaning.

Comment: (But in fact, I'd be prepared to bet money that if you divided all written instances of ***dedicated team*** into two piles - one containing all occurrences immediately preceded by ***and***, and all the rest in the other pile - it would turn out that most in the first pile refer to the ***dedication , loyalty*** of team members, and most in  the second pile would be about being the team being ***exclusively assigned*** to some particular work.

Comment: ...but okay, I take your point. These comments may get deleted, so I'll add something to the Answer text

Comment: Would a *highly dedicated team* also be ambiguous? What about thanking a *dedicated team*?

Comment: You can fiddle around with "edge cases" as much as you like, but you won't find a clear-cut dividing line between the two different contexts, and thus the two different intended meanings. But *on average*, "a **highly** dedicated team" would be very devoted, whereas "a **small** dedicated team" would probably have been exclusively assigned to some task. As ever, words only have meaning in context - and in *another* context, they might mean something completely different.

Comment: @DjinTonic, *dedicated* in sense (1) is a matter of degree, while in sense (2) it is a yes-or-no matter. Anything that implies that dedication is a matter of degree, such as *highly*, will therefore make it clear that it is used in sense (1).